# QEMU aarch64 Guest has not initialized the display (yet)

Tags: operating-system, qemu, arm64

Over the last couple of days, I have been trying to run a QEMU system due to a server that I was setting up. I wanted to protect my actual computer from anything malicious that could get onto it due to a person being able to upload. The speed wasn't great and I realised the problem was likely the fact that the x86_64 emulator doesn't allow for multithreading TCG (well I can't find anything saying it does anyway), and I had the option enabled. I therefore decided I could go use a different architecture because the operating system I would like to use is openSUSE, and it supports aarch64 as well. I have an installer ISO and a QCOW2 disk image. I tried booting the system and then the error came up: "Guest has not initialized the display (yet)".

Here are the command line parameters I am using at the moment:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -cdrom "C:\Users\GHU0002\Downloads\openSUSE-Tumbleweed-NET-aarch64-Snapshot20200421-Media.iso" -drive file=Drive.qcow2 -m 2G -smp 4 -machine sbsa-ref -usbdevice tablet -net nic -net user -accel tcg,thread=multi -vga xenfb -display gtk
```

*Sidenote: I am using the 'sbsa-ref' machine because it is the only one that seemed to support everything I needed: 4 Cores, 2GB RAM, USB, and a CD drive. If it's simply a problem with this, please suggest a different machine I can use.*

My system specs:

- 1.10GHz Celeron N4100 (up to 2.3GHz) (*not great, I know*)
- 4GB RAM
- 128GB SanDisk SSD (not sure which type, but pretty sure that isn't relevant)
- iGPU UHD 600 (*Again, I know*)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found the problem, I hadn't specified a BIOS image... which I didn't realise was required coming from x86_64...

Comment: It's `-bios '/usr/share/qemu/edk2-aarch64-code.fd'` on my system.